# Using non supported currencies on Paypal

Tags: currency, paypal

I have a site with a paypal module. The problem is that the site use as currency "PEN" (Peruvian currency) but it's not supported by Paypal. Is there any way to I gate the supported currencies of paypal or passing the amount in PEN and paypal convert it automatically to USD perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you are underestimating the meaning of "unsupported". Paypal demands that you only use a supported currency throughout the whole payment transaction, and they aren't going to convert unsupported currencies for you.

You should convert currencies on your side: fetch current exchange rates from some web service, list official prices in a supported currency and approximate prices in PEN, and ask the user for Paypal payments in the supported currency.

Comment: sir i am facing issue regarding INR currency,if pass INR currency to paypal its not working i got "Payment not processble" error in my case.sir according to above ur post at my side we need to convert currency every time right?