# PayPal Integration using REST API with ionic - local currency is not supported, is there any live convertion to USD?

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, paypal, ionic3

Currently, I'm developing an ordering app that is made with the Ionic framework and I'm using PayPal REST API. The local currency is not supported by PayPal so I what I did, I put a hard-coded conversion for the total amount to USD before the calling of PayPal API.

I just want to ask if there's a way that I can implement in the app a real-time conversion of the amount with PayPal to get the latest conversion rates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using non supported currencies on Paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432381/using-non-supported-currencies-on-paypal)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43493759/8222905) suggests using [fixer.io](https://github.com/hakanensari/fixer-io) as your currency conversion API. Fixer defaults to EUR, but there are other APIs you could use if it fixer.io doesn't support the currencies you need.